# Can I write on my website and make the code private when the source code is partially copied from an open source GNU GPL V3 project

Tags: gpl, github, contributor, source-code, website

I've rewritten my personal website using this https://github.com/ptrpov/ptrpov . I've made some significant changes. Like I did on my previously (built from scratch) website, I'd like to add ...

Comment: A summary on what the open source software does and how you are going to use it would help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The potential problem that immediately comes to mind is tivoilation.

> Tivoization: Some companies have created various different kinds of devices that run GPLed software, and then rigged the hardware so that they can change the software that's running, but you cannot. If a device can run arbitrary software, it's a general-purpose computer, and its owner should control what it does. When a device thwarts you from doing that, we call that tivoization.

https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.en.html

Comment: @Klaus thank for (http://ptrpov.com)

Comment: It is not clear to me what this answer has to do with the question. Tivoization is about embedding GPL code in consumer devices. Could you please explain the connection between a website and Tivoization?